# Custom TFLite Model in Android, Error in Interpreter Builder

Tags: java, android, c++, tflite, openai-whisper

## Goal & Setup

I was trying to run the whisper model as an tflite model as an android app. I found an existing project that does exactly that: The code is from: [Niranjan Yadla](https://github.com/usefulsensors/openai-whisper) and now want to expand on it. I'm using Java SDK vs 11, NDK vs 21.4 (also tried 25.1) and a tflite schema version of: 3.

The code use the InterpreterBuild from TFLite to create the callable interpreter of the Model and loads the model using FlatBuffer:

```
g_whisper_tflite_params.model =
                tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromBuffer(g_whisper_tflite_params.buffer, g_whisper_tflite_params.size);
```

which seems to successfully load the model.

The g_whisper_tflite_params is a `whisper_tflite` struct:

```
struct whisper_tflite {
    char* buffer = nullptr;
    long size = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<tflite::FlatBufferModel> model;
    tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;
    std::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter> interpreter;
    float *input;

    bool is_whisper_tflite_initialized=false;
};
```

## Problem

but the interpreter part fails:

```
tflite::InterpreterBuilder builder(*(g_whisper_tflite_params.model), g_whisper_tflite_params.resolver);

builder(&(g_whisper_tflite_params.interpreter));
```

results in a linker error:

```
ld: error: undefined symbol: tflite::InterpreterBuilder::operator()(std::__ndk1::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter, std::__ndk1::default_delete<tflite::Interpreter> >*)
>>> referenced by native-lib.cpp:254 (/home/ruzickal/StudioProjects/android_whisper_app_orig/Whisper-TFLIte-Android-Example/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:254)
>>>               CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o:(Java_com_whisper_android_tflitecpp_MainActivity_loadModelJNI)
```

I suspect the error has something to do with my setup, but since I have only little experience working with TFLite I can't find the problem. Any help, also on how I could further debug this problem would be greatly appreciated!